# Error in ternary expression

Tags: c, expression

Consider the following code which shows compile time error :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int x=5,y=0,z=2;
   int a=z?x,y?x:(y); // but z?x,y?x:y:z is not showing any error
    printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

Please help me explain the reason why `z?x,y?x:y:z` is not showing any error?

Comment: This code is very error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it; it's valid and groups like this:

```
z?(x, (y?x:y)):z
```

The middle operand of the conditional expression can be *any* expression.

Answer (score 2):

it is correct..
for each ? exactly one : will be there in 
ternary expressions
that was absent in z?x,y?x:(y);

Answer (score 0):

Comma `,` is not part of ternary expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The `z?x,y?x:y:z` is two ternary expressions.  I would write it as this:

```
z ? (x, y ? x : y) : z
```

There is always exactly one `?` for each `:`.

Comment: I wouldn't write it at all :)